# Strange URLs admin area bug

Tags: wp-admin

I have a strange failure on one of my sites. From time to time, URL's in admin menu changing self on the go like "mysite.com/wp-admin/options.php" => "mysite.com//options.php". It looks like a bug related to the javascript or .htaccess. But I'm not sure. I checked plugins and did not find anything suspicious. I have for example W3 Total Cache. But on other wordpress-sites, created by me I do not have issues with this plugin for example. Is this the only problem with me or did you meet something like that? Please tell me which direction to look. Thanks.

Comment: Really strange, Is it possible you have a security plugin that try to "hide" the "wp-admin" from the url (and fail some times)? You can also check your rewrite rules with a dedicated plugin called "Rewrite Rules Inspector" (maybe it can help).

Comment: It is problem with NextGen gallery plugin